# trimming command line escaped file names using bash's parameter extension

Tags: regex, bash, expansion

let assume i got a command like

`cp file1\ with\ escaped\ spaces file2\ with\ escaped\ spaces`

further i want to handle this command as a string to use parameter extension to gather the filenames with spaces. actually i am able to get the right filename with escapes.

BUT i am not able to get the complete filename for the left one considering the following snippet.

```
$ str="cp file1\ with\ escaped\ spaces file2\ with\ escaped\ spaces";

$ fr=${str##*[^\\] }; echo ${fr}; # gets the rifght one
file2\ with\ escaped\ spaces

$ fl=${str#* }; echo ${fl%%[^\\] *}; # the last expansion strips a `s`
file1\ with\ escaped\ space
```

When i try to get the left one i encouter the problem that the least significant character of this file name is stripped as well.

**I wondered if it is possible gathering the left space escaped filename of the command string using bash's parameter expansion?**

i think i am stuck finding the correct reg exp finding the space not containing a `\`-prefix.

Comment: Why does this command need to be in a string?

Comment: @EtanReisner i want to be able to process the command string passed to a script regarding filenames with escaped characters. i just wanted the "command" look like it would be displayed when running the command on pure shell. atm it is not necessary being a command. please focus on the escapes/regexp/trimming i am stuck with.

Comment: Embedding complex commands inside strings is problematic to impossible to do correctly. That's what I asked. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for details.

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks for pointing at this. anyway i found a weird solution by replacing the right string escaped filename (s.b.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the escape sequences lets remove me the right match.

```
$ str="cp file1\ with\ escaped\ spaces file2\ with\ escaped\ spaces";

$ fr=${str##*[^\\] }; echo ${fr}; # gets the rifght one
file2\ with\ escaped\ spaces

$ fl=${str#* }; echo ${fl// ${fr//\\/\\\\}/};
file1\ with\ escaped\ spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you confuse regexps (used by grep et al.) with glob patterns (used by the shell). In particular, the glob `[^\\] *` matches *a non-backslash followed by a single space, followed by zero or more characters*. Which is exactly what `${fl%%[^\\] *}` strips.

Comment: so how would it look like if i want to trim the longest suffix up to a non-backslash space? i other words how can i get my `s` back? :)

Comment: I didn't want to spoil the satisfaction of solving it yourself. Looks like you were successful. How does that feel? :-)

Comment: thanks. at least it is an solution. feels like flying looping with an aircraft. twice. :) perhaps there is a way using a specific reg exp in parameter expansion but for the moment as you dertermined i am satisfied. remember me and let me know if you come along with something similar.